# How can I get Bing SSL search as the default in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, search

How can I get Bing SSL search as the default from the address bar in Firefox? Or for that matter, at all?

Firefox doesn't seem to allow editing the actual search URLs. `about:config` doesn't have them. The addon repository has normal search, which is already installed.

I figured out how to add a bookmark with the URL `https://www.bing.com/search?q=%s` and the keyword `b` so that typing `b test` in the URL bar opens the page `https://www.bing.com/search?q=test`, but that's not what I want.

It's my one peeve that's keeping me with Chrome (which makes this task dead simple).

Comment: I would just use the add-on `HTTPS Everywhere`.  That sould force bing.com to make a secure connection.  Which is the best solution until the default connection is secure like google.com searches are.

Comment: @Ramhound good suggestion, but Bing support is "Partial, buggy" and it does not affect searches.

Comment: I don't know what to say.  Unil Bing supports non-buggy https searches then there isn't exactly a great deal of options to do https searches

Comment: Bing SSL search itself is fine, which is what my question is about. HTTPS Everywhere just has issues redirecting http to https with Bing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install a Search Plug-in. Go to > http://mycroftproject.com/search-engines.html?name=bing+ssl

And click on any of the two Bing SSL engines (I made the second one just now). Click it and check "Make this current Search Engine".

Or you can make your own search plugins for maximum customisation. http://mycroftproject.com/submitos.html

Comment: Your engine is better because of the minimal URL. Perfection.